# Compare millions of perceptual hashes

Tags: fuzzy-search

I have millions perceptual hashes (length 82) like this

```
0x88006FFF2D9B9D739B7F8A8C7F8E828989858D89858A868888878A88888887898888898887888788
```

I want to match this hash to

```
0x88006FFF2C9C9D739B7F8A8C7F8E828989858D89868A868888878A88888987898888898887888788
```

only couple characters are different, what is best way to find most similar hashes?

Comment: String-Distance would come to mind

Comment: Levenshtein distance? it's way too slow in sql databases, what other databases would you suggest?

Comment: I think that there is more than 1 way to do string distance. If you have any constraints please include them in your question ;)

Comment: I do not but i guess i could add unique id if needed